# SmtpClient works in windowsxp but fails in windows7

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am setting attributes for SmtpClient in program. It works fine in windowsxp but in windows7, it does not work every time. Some time it works and some time fails with failure message. Is there any known issue with SmtpClient in windows 7?

Comment: Have you checked your antivirus logs?

Comment: What's the failure message that you get when it fails?

Comment: What is the failure message you get?  It's easier to provide assistance when we know what the message is.

Comment: Please provide more details (code examples, error messages, etc.) in your question, and give it appropriate and helpful tags.

Comment: Error: "Failure sending mail."

Comment: Dim SmtpServer As New SmtpClient()
SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = True
SmtpServer.Port = 25
SmtpServer.Host = "remote host name"
Dim mail As System.Net.Mail.MailMessage = New MailMessage()
Try
     mail.IsBodyHtml = True
     mail.From = New MailAddress(xFromAdd, xDisplayName, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

     mail.To.Add(xToAdd)

     mail.Subject = xSubject
     mail.Body = xBody
    mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure
     SmtpServer.Send(mail)

Answer (score 0):

There is one issue with SmtpClient that bit me once:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/146711/smtpclient-does-not-gracefully-close-the-underlying-tcp-ip-connection

> After an email has been sent using the SmtpClient, the connection is
>   not gracefully closed. The SmtpClient sends the content, then the
>   . and then terminates the connection. No QUIT command is
>   issued.
>
> The expected behavior is to send a QUIT command before terminating the
>   connection.
>
> The SmtpClient should have a Dispose() methods which would gracefully
>   terminate the connection.

It's been a known issue since 2006.